# Why `substr([], 1)` does not return "rray"?

Tags: php

[Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

> PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable
>   declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which
>   the variable is used.

```
var_dump((string)[]);
```

Output:

```
NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number 3
string(5) "Array"
```

---

```
var_dump(substr([], 1));
```

Output:

```
WARNING substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line number 5
NULL
```

Comment: `Array` is array type and `'Array'` is string type , both are different, you are giving of type array not string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

PHP will not type juggle an array into a string when parsing type arguments.

**Long version**

First of all casting something to a string is handled by function [`_convert_to_string`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ca40664ad62600f781f86755babdc61734b2fdbf/Zend/zend_operators.c#L536) and casting an array to a string is handled by code:

```
case IS_ARRAY:
    zend_error(E_NOTICE, "Array to string conversion");
    zval_ptr_dtor(op);
    ZVAL_NEW_STR(op, zend_string_init("Array", sizeof("Array")-1, 0));
    break;
```

What this does is converts the array to a string but also issue a **notice** that says **Array to string conversion** (important info here).

I couldn't find the explicit documentation but it does seem to be related to the following facts:

1) The source at [zend_types.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/14db98825af38c53a6df276574489b3b08a48558/Zend/zend_types.h) has the following type constants defined:

```
#define IS_UNDEF                    0
#define IS_NULL                     1
#define IS_FALSE                    2
#define IS_TRUE                     3
#define IS_LONG                     4
#define IS_DOUBLE                   5
#define IS_STRING                   6
#define IS_ARRAY                    7
```

There's more but they're not relevant.

2) Internally PHP reads string arguments using [`Z_PARAM_STR`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/571dac8c8f1a7519cf0ede8befd22a0f91416172/Zend/zend_API.h#L1058) there's lots of back and forth in the code there but it boils down to calling [`zend_parse_arg_str_weak`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/41db5f73ce452f4135c61419b6535245dd1e724c/Zend/zend_API.c#L516)

3) This is supposed to be responsible for the type juggling but it has these lines:

```
if (EXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(arg) < IS_STRING)) { 
    convert_to_string(arg);
    *dest = Z_STR_P(arg);
}
```

Meaning that it will not call `convert_to_string` (which in turn calls `_convert_to_string` mentioned above) if the type identifier is less than the string identifier. An array has a type identifier of 7 which is larger than 6 of the string and therefore type juggling will not occur. This is also indicated by the fact that there's no  **Array to string conversion** notice issued meaning the type conversion code does not get called at all.

Objects will receive special treatment in the function `zend_parse_arg_str_weak` which is mainly to call any special string conversion function that the object has (e.g. `__toString`).

Answer (score 1):

`substr` is a build in function and does the type checking [internally](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d77aa8fa6d7916330a8e932b0d0dfd5641a7e966/ext/standard/string.c#L2376). As it expects an string (`Z_PARAM_STR(str)`), an warning is thrown and the function returns `null` immediately without doing anything after the type check.

If you want the same behavior as of your first example, you could also do the type cast manually.

```
var_dump(substr((string)[], 1));
```

Keep in mind, that the conversion from array to string is still "invalid" and throws an notice. There was even an [rfc](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array-to-string) which want to totally deprecate this behavior.

Comment: Then why does `substr(12.5, 1)` return 2.5 instead of complaining about it being a float?

Comment: @apokryfos because `Z_PARAM_STR` is not strict and allows all values, which could be converted to string. Array is not such a type

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) says that *Arrays are always converted to the string "Array"* and nothing about arrays not being convertible to strings.

Comment: @apokryfos true, but that doesn't change anything about the fact, that a warning is rised, if you do this. And the conversion to string is still not automatically done, if you pass an array to a function. `echo` and it's alias `print` are the only two functions I know about, which cast their input

Comment: To clearify this - `Z_PARAM_STR` allows only valus, which don't throw warnings, if you try to convert them to string

Comment: Where can one get the information that `Z_PARAM_STR` allows only values that don't throw warnings. That seems to be the key to the answer to this question.

Comment: You can't - that info is as far as I know only in the source. That notice was introduced in 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php), but I didn't find the exact place in the docs. If you need further information, you could also checkout https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_API.h

Answer (score 0):

it returns `rray`,  you just need to pass `(string)[]` to substr instead of array

```
$a = [];
$b = (string)$a;

echo substr($b, 1);
```

result of this code: https://3v4l.org/UqRqq

`substr` doesn't *cast* variable to string internally because it requires string as the first parameter and operates on strings, that's why you have to cast it manually before passing, otherwise it will just say that it is not a string, it's probably a mechanism helping to find bugs in code, in case you unintentionally pass `array` or `object` to `substr`

Comment: Question is not about this. Question is why `substr` __does not__ convert array to string __internally__.

Comment: "because it requires string as the first parameter and operates on strings" but on [man page](http://php.net/substr) you can see that function works with bool, int and even objects)

Comment: it works on objects that have `__toString()` property

Comment: Yes, it does. But it also works on bools and integers. What's the problem with `array` then?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not type casted when used in substr funtion since substr take string as parameter and array is given.If used this

```
var_dump(substr((string)[], 1));
```

It will return 'rray';

Comment: This is the same as previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially any builtin function can have it's own algorithm for type coercion.
So some function not triggering `[]` to `"Array"` conversion is nothing special.

I only speculate, but in C there is no difference between string and array of characters. So substring of empty array (of characters) is null, or empty array.
Looks like `substr` leaks that behavior to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**Type Juggling experiment :**

```
var_dump(substr("Hello" , 1));
Output : string(4) "ello" 

var_dump(substr(Hello , 1));
Output : string(4) "ello" 

var_dump(substr(10000 , 1));
Output : string(4) "0000"  

var_dump((string)[]); 
Output : Array

var_dump(substr((string)[], 1));  
Output : rray

var_dump(substr(false , 1));
Output : bool(false) 

var_dump(substr(1 , 1));
Output : bool(false) 

var_dump(substr(array() , 1)); 
Output : string(5) "Array" NULL substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 6 

var_dump(substr(&&& , 1));
Output : syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) 

var_dump(substr(class , 1));
output : syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) 

var_dump(substr(BREAK , 1));
syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK)
```

**Conclusion**( Based on above sample set) : PHP type cast first parameter of substr() as string only if it is not a reserve strings.

---